# LUA read text file, make split and send to array

Tags: lua

i am new to lua. actually this script use for game server but i need help for getting the value from my store .txt file. so my store system is each players will be save on one file.

### Store File

my syntax data from text file

```
[name]:[points]:[which var point earned on index]
```

my example data (this var point actually the written data from lua file that sended to text file)

```
jack:60:4
ronald:40:1
jack:30:1
```

so when i got from above is the list of

```
local player = {{(name),(points),(which var point earned on index)},
                {(name),(points),(which var point earned on index)},...};
```

My own code

```
local line_data = {}
local point_file = io.open("points.txt", "r")
for line in point_file:lines() do
  local playername, playerpoint, playervarpointname = line:match("(%d+):(%d+):(%d+)")
  local player_data = {playername, playerpoint, playervarpointname}
  for i = 1, #line do
        player_data = [#player_data + 1] = line[i];
  end
  line_data[#line_data + 1] = player_data
end
```

is this the correct code ?

Comment: Why aren't you using a SQLite database here? It'd perform better when you've to filter records etc.

Comment: Also, what is this line for: `player_data = [#player_data + 1] = line[i]`?

Comment: 1) `line:match("^(.-):(%d+):(%d+)$")` 2) Remove `for i = 1, #line do .. end` loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
local line_data = {}
local point_file = io.open("points.txt", "r")
for line in point_file:lines() do
  local playername, playerpoint, playervarpointname = line:match("([^:]+):(%d+):(%d+)")
  local player_data = {playername, playerpoint, playervarpointname}
 table.insert(line_data, player_data)
end
```

Or , imho, '[a-zA-Z0-9]+ ' , may be used instead of '[^:]+'

Comment: Your loop block could be simplified to one statement: line_data[#line_data+1] = { line:match('([^:]+):(%d+):(%d+)') }